# Is $ \mathbb{C}^\times $ a subset of $ \mathbb{C}^{+} $?

Tags: group-theory

Say we have an additive group of a field $ \mathbb{C} $, $ G = (\mathbb{C}, + ) $.
This of course means that for $ z_{1}, z_{2} \in G $, $ z_{1} + z_{2} \in G $.
Now we all remember that multiplication was defined through addition.
So my question is: For $ z_{1}, z_{2} \in (\mathbb{C}, \times) $ if we use the definition of multiplication through addition (i.e., $ab =a + a+ a ...$, $b$ times), does this mean that $ z_{1} \times z_{2}  \in G$?

My consideration is as follows. We define $ \mathbb{C}^{+} $ as $ (\mathbb{C}, + ) $ as a set of all complex numbers with binary operation  $ "+"$. Now we define $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ as $ (\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}, \times  ) $. Doesn't it mean that $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is a subset of $ \mathbb{C}^{+} $?

Comment: For a general complex number $b$ it's senseless to add "$b$ times".

Comment: $\mathbb Zi$ is an additive subgroup of $\mathbb C$ as $ai+bi=(a+b)i$.

Comment: @ Cave Johnson. I do realize this. However, say $ \sqrt{a} \times \sqrt{b}   \in (\mathbb{R}, \times)$.  $ \sqrt{a} \times \sqrt{b}  $  is also in $ (\mathbb{R}, +) $ as it is in $ \mathbb{R} $, even though we can't add $ \sqrt{a} $ to itself  $\sqrt{b}$ times...

Comment: If you mean "$\mathbb{C}^\times$ is a homomorphic image of $\mathbb{C}^+$", then the answer is "no", since $i^4=1$ but no complex number $z$ except $0$ satisfies $4z=0$.

Comment: Stricly as stated, $0$ is a homorphic image of any group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since no reasonable argument was presented to disprove my claim, I'll go ahead and answer my own question. Yes, for the field $ \mathbb{C} $, the group $ \mathbb{C}^{\times} $ (as a set) is a subset (but obviously, not a subgroup) of $  \mathbb{C}^{+}$. 
This means that for any two non-zero elements $ a,b  \in \mathbb{C}^{+} $, their product, $ a \times b $ (defined as the usual product of two elements in $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$) is also in $ \mathbb{C}^{+} $.

Comment: So your question was if $\mathbb{C} \setminus  \{0\} $ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Sure :) But I did manage to confuse everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Every commutative additive groups is 'automatically' a $\mathbb{Z}$ module via 'repeated addition' and thus one can define multiplication "by integers" yet one cannot defined a multiplication of arbitrary elements based on addition only.

To wit, consider an additive group with three elements $\{0,a,b\}$.
Now it is must hold that $a+a=b$ and $a+a+a=0$ so $2a=b$, $3a=0$, $4a=a$ etc. And the same for $b$.

Yet based on this you cannot decided what $a\times a$ is. It could be $a$ or $b$.

Or $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$ are "the same" (isomorphic) as additive groups, but the multiplication is fundamentally different (the fields are not isomorphic).

Comment: @user369044 What makes you say that?  $(\sqrt{2}\Bbb Z,+)$ is a group (where $\sqrt{2}\Bbb Z=\{\sqrt{2}z~:~z\in\Bbb Z\}=\{\dots,-3\sqrt{2},-2\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2},0,\sqrt{2},2\sqrt{2},\dots\}$) yet $\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}=2$ is not an element of $\sqrt{2}\Bbb Z$.  It depends on what multiplication is in your context... Even if it is a binary operation with the image being among $\{0,a,b\}$, without explicitly defining what $\times$ does beyond that, there is no guarantee that it satisfies the desired properties.  For example with $x\times y = x$ for all $x,y$

Comment: @user369044 you wrote "*no matter what $a\times a$ is, it is an element of that group*", I was disputing that statement.